# What are the L1 and L2 components in the raspberry pi zero and their values?

Tags: pi-zero

My raspberry pi zero v 1.3 has been damaged due to a short circuit of the IO pins and it does not turn on, I have been looking closely and I have notice that the L1 and L2 components are melted. Someone know what this components are and their values?

[image: Here I show what the components in the red circles (the photo is not from my raspberry pi zero)]

Comment: why downvoted? this could help many others

Comment: look at [schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_Zero_1p3_reduced.pdf) - they are inductors I believe (look top left)

Comment: I also think that L1, L2 are the two inductors connected to  PAM2306.  I guess they are now burnt/ open circuit due to over current.  Perhaps you can replace them by both 4u7 (you might desolder simiiar looking things from scrap PCBs）.  If you could not find inductors, you may take a risk and just short circuit them (10% chance that something would explode!)

Comment: You say L1 and L2 are melted.  These are passive components.  Them having melted suggest a pretty major fault in other components which have themselves almost certainly being destroyed.  I think you are wasting time and money in even attempting such an uneconomic repair.

Comment: Thank you all, Its probably useless but I will try to replace those inductors and see what happens

Comment: You can buy a board with the inductors already mounted for $5 - it even comes with a free Pi.